# Pass ArrayList objects to another acivity by reference

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I have one activity that sends an object arraylist to another activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Value> values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        values = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("Values", values);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 1:
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("Values",values);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I add or remove a value in any other activity the `ArrayList` doesn't change in my MainActivity. For example:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<Value> values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ...

        values = (ArrayList<Value>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Values");

        ...

        values.add(value1, value2);
        this.finish();
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to know how I should send my ArrayList by reference so I can add, remove or modify it without losing the changes.

Comment: One option would be to follow what is shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to send the changes back to the original activity using `onActivityResult(...)`.

Comment: I think the proper way is to handle the changes somewhere. For example store in DB or SharedPreferences - and init the list from there, or listen onSharedPreferenceChanged(). Also you can pass back the modified list. A lot of solutions. Those are more than enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra data you pass in an `Intent` is serialized and as such cannot be passed by reference.

A simple solution would be using a `static` field somewhere to share the data between the `Activity`s

Comment: Arent there chances that the previous activity (which contains the static field) has been GC-ed? Could store this ArrayList in the Application instance instead? (:

Comment: There is a possibility I suppose but not a likely chance, AFAIK, that the ClassLoader for the Activity will be GCed and thus the static field. Extending Application and putting the static field there would definitely eliminate all chance though.